# Python (best) or C++: How to hook onto a system message?

Tags: python, c++, windows, hook

I'm trying to hook onto a Windows message such as WM_DELETE_WINDOW.

I know that in tkinter (Python), `root.bind` can do it, but is there a way without having GUI?

I'm not sure if Python import signal can do it.

Thanks!